# how to access header in lumen routing file(web.php)

Tags: lumen

how to access header in routing file lumen ?

i want to use header parameters values as namespace in route group in web.php.

example :

```
$router->group(['namespace' => 'Request::header('version')'], function() use ($router) 
{
    $router->post('login', 'UserController@loginUser');
    $router->post('test', 'UserController@testApi');
});
```

if request header version param v1 then it use v1 namespace,if v2 then use v2 namespace.something like versioning.

Comment: If you meant by accessing the request header, if you pass `$request` to controller (eg. `public function index(Request $request)`) or middleware (eg. `handle($request, Closure $next)`) as parameter, you should be able to get them as `$request->header('yourheaderkey')`.  But looking at your approach for versioning, I think it'd be better to make 2 different route group to 2 different route file.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a way to grab the version from header, you can try putting `Request` as callback parameter as seen:

```
$router->get('/head', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    return $request->header('version');
});
```

above should return whatever value you put as header with `version` key.

But I personally suggest you to try separating the route group for this. Say you'll have

```
$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Api', 
    'prefix'=> 'api/v1/',
    'middleware' => ['jwt.auth', 'student_access_token']
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php';
});
```

and then for other version you just define the same on `bootstrap/app.php` directing to other route files. Hope it helps.

Comment: i did it using  $_SERVER function in app.php 
first get header using $_SERVER['HTTP_VERSION'] and decide which version of route file to use.
i am not sure this is right or wrong approach

Comment: my app.php code 
 
$version = 'v1';
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_VERSION'])) {
    $version = $_SERVER['HTTP_VERSION'];
}
switch ($version) {
    case 'v2':
        $app->router->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\v2'], function ($router) {
            require __DIR__ . '/../routes/v2.php';
        });
        break;
    default :
        $app->router->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\v1'], function ($router) {
            require __DIR__ . '/../routes/v1.php';
        });
        break;
}
return $app;